# merge Post.query.filter and Post.query.order_by

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

i want show my posts in the blog filtred by categories and also ordered from newest to oldest so how can i merge between these two in my code

```
posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=7)
```

and

```
posts = Post.query.filter_by(category = 'Academic').paginate(page=page, per_page=7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query attribute of a model is of type `<class 'flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery'>`, and so is `Post.query.filter_by(...)`. This means that you can infinitely stack filter_by and order_by, like this:

```
posts = Post.query.filter_by(category='Academic').order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=7)
```